# confluence display content by user

Tags: confluence

I am trying to get specific content on a confluence cloud wiki to display content based on a specific user. The scenario here is that there are links on a page but only 1 should display, the one that displays is based on whom ever is logged in.

I have been told how a macro is the way forward, but I have read the documentation and I am at a loss. I do not understand what I have to do or how to write a confluence macro. could someone help me out with either an example or some links? I have searched like crazy, but maybe i am not asking the right questions but hopfully you can all help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a plugin for this:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.customware.confluence.plugin.visibility

But I'm not sure how thoroughly it hides the content. It might still be visible if users view the page source. If you're trying to hide content which needs to be really protected, you'll probably need to do something else.

Depending on how many users are going to be using the page, you could also just make separate spaces for them, add the permissions to those spaces, and then use a page-include on your "main" page to display the content. If they don't have access it shouldn't show up. You might experience some formatting issues with that solution, however.

Finally, you could grab the username with jquery and display stuff based on that. This solution will be pretty easy if you are familiar with javascript/jquery.

Edit: Here are some helpful resources on how to use javascript and jquery within confluence:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/How+to+Use+JavaScript+in+Confluence
https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/writing-confluence-plugins/including-javascript-and-css-resources

Comment: I am a web developer, though I have never used confluence so do not know really what I could / can do with it using Jquery would be ok didnt know I could use it within confluence... in regards to the plugin that only works on server not cloud :( security isnt a big issue in regards to this its just niceties

Comment: Are you going to be specifying a lot of different content for a lot of individual users, or will it be a fairly small amount? Because if it wouldn't mean creating more than maybe a few extra spaces, I would just create a space and only give one or two people permission to view that space. Then use a page-include on your "main" page to display content based on permission.

Comment: its very small content, I agree with you completely spaces would just be easier and make more sense... but I have been told it has to be done this way. haha any ideas how i can get this working on the cloud?

Comment: When asking questions about confluence cloud / hosted you should reference it in the question and in the tag because the cloud has more limitations than the standalone Confluence server version. In this case the [https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.customware.confluence.plugin.visibility/server/overview](free visibility plugin designed for this) can't be installed on Confluence Cloud, and neither can the [https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.swift.confluence.html/server/overview](HTML Plugin) for which can be used to insert JavaScript into a page to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Also, Confluence Cloud has restrictions on Administrator actions including that you can't create User Macros. You could easily code this in the User Macro on Confluence Server.